# Text overflows padding

Tags: html, css

I was working on a website when I discovered a problem. Some text is not breaking where it supposed to. The text just ignores the padding and breaks when its passed the full width.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fw-heading.fw-heading-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.fw-heading {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.fw-heading .fw-special-title {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.fw-heading .fw-special-title::before {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #002e50;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.fw-heading .fw-special-title span {
  background: #fff;
  font: inherit;
  padding: .5rem 1.5rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="fw-heading fw-heading-h2 fw-heading-center">
  <h2 class="fw-special-title"><span>"Ons meubilair is extreem licht, oersterk en afgestemd op ergonomische houdingen."</span>
  </h2>
</div>
```

I've tried to make the padding bigger and overflow: hidden. But none of these work.

Can you help me?

Comment: You could make the padding bigger, the font smaller or use `overflow: hidden;` or `scroll;`

Comment: Than this happens [link](https://imgur.com/a/V1onoj3)

Comment: can you try giving `display:block` to span

Comment: `display: block` won't work in my situation, because the sides of the span, minus the padding, won't touch the sides of the text inside it...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```css
.fw-heading .fw-special-title span {
background : #fff;
font : inherit;
padding: 0 1.5rem;
display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="fw-heading">
<h2 class="fw-special-title">
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio, molestias, enim! Beatae cumque, eum amet vero nihil accusantium labore? Soluta quos perspiciatis eius aut, nulla, expedita eveniet necessitatibus aperiam assumenda!</span>
</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work because the pseudo element needs to be visible. Now it isn't

Comment: you have to give the full css then from what you posted we just understand that it also overflows from its width

Comment: I've posted a snippet which includes all the css needed

Answer (score 0):

You should use display:block with span, eg-

```
<div style="width:500px;">
<h2 class="asses">
  <span>
  Mauris fermentum massa eu tortor iaculis placerat. Nulla dapibus commodo libero,
  </span>
 </h2>
 </div>
.asses span{
     background:red;
     padding:0 1.5rem;
     display:block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
display:block
```

and if you have other css over this maybe add also !important (property will always be applied).

Answer (score 0):

Giving your span a `display` of `block` and changing the `padding` to `margin` will give you the result you want. The difference is that padding will **add** space to the background (that is white), which will cover the pseudo-element behind it, whereas margin will **push** the space away from the background of span, so that whatever is behind it is still visible.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fw-heading.fw-heading-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.fw-heading {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.fw-heading .fw-special-title {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.fw-heading .fw-special-title::before {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #002e50;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.fw-heading .fw-special-title span {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  font: inherit;
  margin: .5rem 1.5rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="fw-heading fw-heading-h2 fw-heading-center">
  <h2 class="fw-special-title"><span>"Ons meubilair is extreem licht, oersterk en afgestemd op ergonomische houdingen."</span>
  </h2>
</div>
```